# Download PNG through tor using java

Tags: java, download, png, tor

I want to download a PNG from a remote web server through the tor proxy. The proxy is up and running and I can send the necessary GET and receive the OK using a tor socket. I can also receive the content. However, I don't manage to parse the content. My goal is to have a method I can pass a connected socket (preconfigured by me to use the Tor network) and get back an BufferedImage. How can I do that?

My GET request looks like the following:

```
PrintStream httpOut = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());
httpOut.print("GET /" + path + " HTTP/1.0\r\n");
httpOut.print("Host: " + host + ":" + port + "\r\n");
httpOut.print("\r\n");
httpOut.flush();
```

And an example response would be:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 23 Feb 2015 20:54:25 GMT
Server: Apache
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=thesessionideeee; path=/
Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Last-Modified: Mon, 23 Feb 2015 20:54:25GMT
Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0
Content-Length: 3884
Connection: close
Content-Type: image/png
```

Thank you for help,
Turakar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this class from http://web.mit.edu/foley/www/TinFoil/src/tinfoil/TorLib.java
that explain how to connect:

```
    package tinfoil;

/**
 * Tinfoil is an RFID Privacy and Security Enhancement library.
 *
 *     Copyright (c) 2005 Joe Foley, MIT AutoID Labs

 Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a
 copy of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"),
 to deal in the Software without restriction, including without limitation
 the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense,
 and/or sell copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the
 Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

 The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included
 in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

 THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS
 OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
 FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
 AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
 LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
 OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS
 IN THE SOFTWARE.
 */
// $HeadURL: $
// $Id: $

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;

/**
 * The Onion Router Java Library routines<br />
 * These methods allow us to setup an anonymized TCP socket through the Tor
 * network and do safe anonymized DNS lookups.<br />
 * This code was written with the help of Roger Dingledine and Nick Mathewson.<br />
 * The code is open-source under the MIT X11 license.
 * <ul>
 * <li><a href = "http://tor.eff.org"> http://tor.eff.org</a>
 * <li><a href =
 * "http://tor.eff.org/cvs/control/doc/howto.txt">http://tor.eff.org
 * /cvs/control/doc/howto.txt</a>
 * <li><a href =
 * "http://www.mokabyte.it/2000/06/firewallutil.htm">http://www.mokabyte
 * .it/2000/06/firewallutil.htm</a>
 * </ul>
 *
 * @author Joe Foley<foley at MIT dot EDU>, MIT AutoID Labs
 * @version 1.0
 *          <p>
 */
public class TorLib {
    /**
     * Default TOR Proxy port.
     */
    static int proxyPort = 9050;
    /**
     * Default TOR Proxy hostaddr.
     */
    static String proxyAddr = "localhost";
    /**
     * Constant tells SOCKS4/4a to connect. Use it in the <i>req</i> parameter.
     */
    final static byte TOR_CONNECT = (byte) 0x01;
    /**
     * Constant tells TOR to do a DNS resolve. Use it in the <i>req</i>
     * parameter.
     */
    final static byte TOR_RESOLVE = (byte) 0xF0;
    /**
     * Constant indicates what SOCKS version are talking Either SOCKS4 or
     * SOCKS4a
     */
    final static byte SOCKS_VERSION = (byte) 0x04;
    /**
     * SOCKS uses Nulls as field delimiters
     */
    final static byte SOCKS_DELIM = (byte) 0x00;
    /**
     * Setting the IP field to 0.0.0.1 causes SOCKS4a to be enabled.
     */
    final static int SOCKS4A_FAKEIP = 0x01;

    /**
     * This method allows you to demo/access the resolver/socket generation from
     * the command line. Run with "-h" to get the help menu.
     *
     * @param args
     *            Command line arguments for test main method.
     */
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        String req = "-r";
        String targetHostname = "tor.eff.org";
        String targetDir = "index.html";
        int targetPort = 80;

        if ((args.length > 0) && args[0].equals("-h")) {
            System.out.println("Tinfoil/TorLib - interface for using Tor from Java\n" + "By Joe Foley<foley@mit.edu>\n"
                    + "Usage: java Tinfoil.TorLib <cmd> <args>\n" + "<cmd> can be: -h for help\n"
                    + "              -r for resolve\n" + "              -w for wget\n" + "For -r, the arg is:\n"
                    + "  <hostname> Hostname to DNS resolve\n" + "For -w, the args are:\n"
                    + "   <host> <path> <optional port>\n"
                    + " for example, http://tor.eff.org:80/index.html would be\n" + "   tor.eff.org index.html 80\n"
                    + " Since this is a demo, the default is the tor website.\n");
            System.exit(2);
        }

        if (args.length >= 4) {
            targetPort = new Integer(args[2]).intValue();
        }
        if (args.length >= 3) {
            targetDir = args[2];
        }
        if (args.length >= 2) {
            targetHostname = args[1];
        }
        if (args.length >= 1) {
            req = args[0];
        }

        if (req.equals("-r")) {
            System.out.println(TorResolve(targetHostname));
        } else if (req.equals("-w")) {
            try {
                Socket s = TorSocket(targetHostname, targetPort);
                DataInputStream is = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
                PrintStream out = new java.io.PrintStream(s.getOutputStream());

                // Construct an HTTP request
                out.print("GET  /" + targetDir + " HTTP/1.0\r\n");
                out.print("Host: " + targetHostname + ":" + targetPort + "\r\n");
                out.print("Accept: */*\r\n");
                out.print("Connection: Keep-Aliv\r\n");
                out.print("Pragma: no-cache\r\n");
                out.print("\r\n");
                out.flush();

                // this is from Java Examples In a Nutshell
                final InputStreamReader from_server = new InputStreamReader(is);
                char[] buffer = new char[1024];
                int chars_read;

                // read until stream closes
                while ((chars_read = from_server.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    // loop through array of chars
                    // change \n to local platform terminator
                    // this is a nieve implementation
                    for (int j = 0; j < chars_read; j++) {
                        if (buffer[j] == '\n') {
                            System.out.println();
                        } else {
                            System.out.print(buffer[j]);
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.flush();
                }
                s.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method Creates a socket, then sends the inital SOCKS request info It
     * stops before reading so that other methods may differently interpret the
     * results. It returns the open socket.
     *
     * @param targetHostname
     *            The hostname of the destination host.
     * @param targetPort
     *            The port to connect to
     * @param req
     *            SOCKS/TOR request code
     * @return An open Socket that has been sent the SOCK4a init codes.
     * @throws IOException
     *             from any Socket problems
     */
    static Socket TorSocketPre(final String targetHostname, final int targetPort, final byte req) throws IOException {

        Socket s;
        // System.out.println("Opening connection to "+targetHostname+":"+targetPort+
        // " via proxy "+proxyAddr+":"+proxyPort+" of type "+req);
        s = new Socket(proxyAddr, proxyPort);
        DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
        os.writeByte(SOCKS_VERSION);
        os.writeByte(req);
        // 2 bytes
        os.writeShort(targetPort);
        // 4 bytes, high byte first
        os.writeInt(SOCKS4A_FAKEIP);
        os.writeByte(SOCKS_DELIM);
        os.writeBytes(targetHostname);
        os.writeByte(SOCKS_DELIM);
        return (s);
    }

    /**
     * This method creates a socket to the target host and port using
     * TorSocketPre, then reads the SOCKS information.
     *
     * @param targetHostname
     *            Hostname of destination host.
     * @param targetPort
     *            Port on remote destination host.
     * @return Fully initialized TCP Socket that tunnels to the target Host/Port
     *         via the Tor Proxy host/port.
     * @throws IOException
     *             when Socket and Read/Write exceptions occur.
     */
    static Socket TorSocket(final String targetHostname, final int targetPort) throws IOException {
        Socket s = TorSocketPre(targetHostname, targetPort, TOR_CONNECT);
        DataInputStream is = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());

        // only the status is useful on a TOR CONNECT
        byte version = is.readByte();
        byte status = is.readByte();
        if (status != (byte) 90) {
            // failed for some reason, return useful exception
            throw (new IOException(ParseSOCKSStatus(status)));
        }
        // System.out.println("status: "+ParseSOCKSStatus(status));
        int port = is.readShort();
        int ipAddr = is.readInt();
        return (s);
    }

    /**
     * This method opens a TOR socket, and does an anonymous DNS resolve through
     * it. Since Tor caches things, this is a very fast lookup if we've already
     * connected there The resolve does a gethostbyname() on the exit node.
     *
     * @param targetHostname
     *            String containing the hostname to look up.
     * @return String representation of the IP address: "x.x.x.x"
     */
    static String TorResolve(final String targetHostname) {
        int targetPort = 0; // we dont need a port to resolve

        try {
            Socket s = TorSocketPre(targetHostname, targetPort, TOR_RESOLVE);
            DataInputStream is = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());

            byte version = is.readByte();
            byte status = is.readByte();
            if (status != (byte) 90) {
                // failed for some reason, return useful exception
                throw (new IOException(ParseSOCKSStatus(status)));
            }
            int port = is.readShort();
            byte[] ipAddrBytes = new byte[4];
            is.read(ipAddrBytes);
            InetAddress ia = InetAddress.getByAddress(ipAddrBytes);
            // System.out.println("Resolved into:"+ia);
            is.close();
            String addr = ia.toString().substring(1); // clip off the "/"
            return (addr);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return (null);
    }

    /**
     * This helper method allows us to decode the SOCKS4 status codes into Human
     * readible input.<br />
     * Based upon info from
     * http://archive.socks.permeo.com/protocol/socks4.protocol
     *
     * @param status
     *            Byte containing the status code.
     * @return String human-readible representation of the error.
     */
    static String ParseSOCKSStatus(final byte status) {
        // func to turn the status codes into useful output
        // reference
        String retval;
        switch (status) {
        case 90:
            retval = status + " Request granted.";
            break;
        case 91:
            retval = status + " Request rejected/failed - unknown reason.";
            break;
        case 92:
            retval = status + " Request rejected: SOCKS server cannot connect to identd on the client.";
            break;
        case 93:
            retval = status + " Request rejected: the client program and identd report different user-ids.";
            break;
        default:
            retval = status + " Unknown SOCKS status code.";
        }
        return (retval);

    }
}
```

Comment: The Problem is not connect with for, but to download a PNG through it. I can't use the ImageIO library from java, because it can only handle URLs. I will edit my question to clarify that.

Comment: You can download the image to a byte array and then generate a BufferedImage from it like this: InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageInByte);
BufferedImage bImageFromConvert = ImageIO.read(in);